# How to use SWITCH statement with dates as one of the conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am having a bit of tough time wrapping my head around this. I have a column based on response time in hours and our company's SLA (service level agreement) is that all incoming inquires should be answered within 2 days (the response time in hours is total hours spent on responding to inquiry).

The problem is that our company operates with winter time (7 h 45 min) and summer time (7 h). My dataset consist both and I want Power BI to differientiate winter and summer time when I try to compute SLA. In winter time 1 working day = 7 h 45 min and in summer time = 7 h. I have just used the average of summer/winter time = 7 h 30 min. The SLA column consist 3 data types, "Innen en arbeidsdag", "Innen to arbeidsdager" and "over 2 arbeidsdager".

My dataset is called 'Masterdata' and I have used this syntax so far:

```
SLA =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    Masterdata[Svartid i t] > 15, "Over to arbeidsdager",
    Masterdata[Svartid i t] > 7.5, "Innen to arbeidsdager",
    Masterdata[Svartid i t] <= 7.5, "Innen en arbeidsdag"
)
```

```
Svartid i t | SLA
------------|----------------------
 6,12       | Innen en arbeidsdag
11,73       | Innen to arbeidsdager
20,42       | Over to arbeidsdager
1,07        | Innen en arbeidsdag
```

How can I use DATES in this syntax to tell Power BI that data in 'Svartid i t' (response time) YTD column ,from 15th May to 15th September, is summer time (Working day = 7 h)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extend your **calculated column** formula:

```
SLA = 
VAR hours = 
    IF( 
        AND(
            AND(
                MONTH(MasterData[YTD]) >= 5,
                DAY(MasterData[YTD]) >= 15
            ),
            AND(
                MONTH(MasterData[YTD]) <= 9,
                DAY(MasterData[YTD]) <= 15
            )
        ),
        7,
        7.45
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] > 2 * hours, "Over to arbeidsdager",
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] > hours, "Innen to arbeidsdager",
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] <= hours, "Innen en arbeidsdag"
    )
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your syntax should be correct, but it seems that I have the wrong date format. I'm using European format (dd/mm/yyyy), is that why the IF condition doesn't work? Data between 15.05. - 15.09. doesn't return "Innen to arbeidsdager" when 'Svartid i t' is greater then 7 h and less or equal to 14 h.

Comment: The DAY and MONTH function work on the `Date` data type (which is internally an integer number), not on formatted text. Make sure your Masterdata[YTD] has the `Date` data type.

Comment: Yes, Masterdata[YTD] has the 'Date' data type that's why I find it strange.

Comment: The column 'svartid i t' is a numeric calculated column

Comment: Doesn't matter if it was created with Power Query or DAX.

Comment: Answer accepted. I appreciate your help.